# Why automatic rotation does not work correctly while swipe back?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate, interactivepopgesture

If during the swipe back to turn the device, then a black area appearing, see the images.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8JcM.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/95bMG.png)

If in the project settings to enable "Require full screen", then this problem disappears, but I cannot enable "Require full screen" as I also need to use my application in "Split Mode". 
If someone faced this let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call `self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()` in the `viewDidAppear()` method in the controller in which an error occurs.